# substitution of 64kbyte binary by 64kbyte silence in endless audio stream on commandline

Tags: bash, sed, stream, wget, mplayer

I try to do some stream manipulation with webradio streams. Goal is to use a pattern in triggerfile to substitute some seconds of the instream to silence in the outstream.

I found bbe to possibly fit for that if I could bring something like

```
bbe -e "s/c:\\temp\\jingle.img/c:\\temp\\silence.txt/" file1
```

to work

```
(see >man bbe  
...EXAMPLES
bbe -e "s/c:\\temp\\data1.txt/c:\\temp\\data2.txt/" file1
          all  occurrences  of  "c:\temp\data1.txt"  in  file  file1  are
          changed to "c:\temp\data2.txt"
```

But on my linux machine (bash 4.1.5) I fail to get the pattern file to be read.

Trials like `"s/$(cat jingle.img)/...` are denied because of false escaping or size too big.

Assume 64k files of random data
/home/jingle.img and
/home/silence.img

What I have but only scrambles the sound a little and is limited to 128 byte pattern is

```
wget -q -O - "$@" http://ds7.comcities.com:8033/stream | bbe -e "s/\x97/\x01/" | mplayer -cache 10000 -cache-min 4 -
```

So how to silence the jingle stored in jingle.img ?